# Update date format in SQL from 1980-12-17 00:00:00.000 to 17-Dec-80 in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Want to update from data type of Date which is now `1980-12-17  00:00:00.000` to `17-Dec-80` in Microsoft SQL Server management studio

and I m trying to do update command

```
UPDATE emp SET HIREDATE = 17-Dec-80 WHERE EMPNO= 7369;
```

But I'm getting error.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'Dec'

Comment: Please add error that you get.

Comment: @TekNath  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Dec'.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to change the data type date to a string format.

Comment: `DATE` columns don't have "a format"  so you can't change the way the value is saved. Just apply the formatting you want when you _display_ (or retrieve) the values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   how to apply  formatting? you means to say insert new sql ?

Comment: This link will help you convert date [LINK](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: In older SQL Server versions use `convert()` newer ones have a [`format()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format date on MS SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394002/how-to-format-date-on-ms-sql-server-2008)

Comment: [*DateTime* does not have a display format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30033028/3094533). Only string representations of datetime values have a display format.

Comment: 17 minus DEC minus 80? And you have no DEC column.

Comment: the column name is HIREDATE and not DEC

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [Format is nice and all, but...](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: @ZoharPeled This is what i want .....may this link will help me...thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE emp
SET HIREDATE = '17-Dec-80'
WHERE EMPNO= 7369;
```

For more info visit this [LINK](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: Why bother converting a string to `varchar`? this makes no sense.

Comment: @DiwakarYadav that happens because your data type is datetime so it adds time in the date.

Comment: @Buchiman so what should be data type so that i will get date as 17-Dec-80

Answer (score 0):

As a_horse_with_no_name says in the comments, a DATE column doesn't have a format, what you're seeing when you SELECT it is a default human readable format of the date. If you want to see something different you specify your required format.

```
SELECT FORMAT(HIREDATE, 'dd-MMM-yy')
  FROM emp
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To set the date use:

```
UPDATE emp SET HIREDATE = '17-Dec-80' WHERE EMPNO= 7369;
```

To retrieve it in the "dd-MMM-yy" format:

```
select 
   format(HIREDATE, 'dd-MMM-yy') as HIREDATE  
from emp 
WHERE 
   EMPNO= 7369
```