# How to get daily budget based on monthly budget and workings days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have have 2 tables.

One table with month budget, and one table with workings days.

What I want, is find out daily budget based on the monthly budget and working days.

Example:

August have a budget on 1000 and have 21 workings day.
September have a budget on 2000 and 23 workings days

I want to figure out what the total budget betweens two dates.
Ex: between *2020-08-02* and *2020-09-15*
But must be sure that, days in august takes budget from august, days from september takes budget from september etc.

**tbBudget:**

```
Date | Amount
2020-08-01 | 1000
2020-09-01 | 2000
2020-10-01 | 3000
```

**tbWorkingDays**

```
Date | WorkingDay 

2020-08-01 | 0
2020-08-02 | 0
2020-08-03 | 1
2020-08-04 | 1
2020-08-05 | 1
2020-08-06 | 1
2020-08-07 | 1
2020-08-08 | 1
...
2020-09-01 | 1
2020-09-02 | 1
2020-09-03 | 0
2020-09-04 | 1
...
2020-10-01 | 1
2020-10-02 | 0
2020-10-03 | 1
2020-10-04 | 1
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue. Can you help me?

My result should be like:

```
Date | WorkingDay | BudgetAmount
2020-08-02 | 0 | 0.0
2020-08-03 | 1 | 47.6
2020-08-04 | 1 | 47.6
2020-08-05 | 1 | 47.6
..
2020-09-13 | 1 | 86.9
2020-09-14 | 1 | 86.9
2020-09-15 | 1 | 86.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE and group by:

```
with CTE1 AS(
SELECT FORMAT(A.DATE, 'MMyyyy') DATE, B.AMOUNT, SUM(CASE WHEN [WorkingDay] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_WORKING_DAYS
FROM tbWorkingDays A INNER JOIN tbBudget B
ON (FORMAT(A.DATE, 'MMyyyy') = FORMAT(B.DATE, 'MMyyyy')) GROUP BY FORMAT(A.[DATE], 'MMyyyy'), B.AMOUNT
)
SELECT A.DATE, 
A.WORKINGDAY, 
CASE WHEN A.WORKINGDAY = 1 THEN B.AMOUNT/B.TOTAL_WORKING_DAYS 
        ELSE 0 END AS BudgetAmount
FROM CTE1 B 
INNER JOIN 
tbWorkingDays A 
ON (FORMAT(A.DATE, 'MMyyyy') = B.DATE);
```

Comment: I got 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. - think is because of a old sql server. Can use an other fuction instead of FORMAT?

Comment: Which version you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6001: Service Pack 1)

Comment: You can create used defined function as per following post: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3820771/Formatted-date-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Comment: or this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394002/how-to-format-date-on-ms-sql-server-2008#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=SELECT%20FORMAT(GETDATE()%2C%20',similar%20in%20SQL%20Server%202008.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the budgets are by month:

```
select wd.*,
       (case when workingday = 0 then 0
             else wd.budget * 1.0 / sum(wd.workingday) over (partition by wd.date)
        end) as daily_amount
from tbWorkingDays wd join
     tblBudget b 
     on wd.date >= b.date and wd.date < dateadd(month, 1, wd.date);
```

If the budget dates are not per month, then use `apply` instead:

```
select wd.*,
       (case when workingday = 0 then 0
             else wd.budget * 1.0 / sum(wd.workingday) over (partition by wd.date)
        end) as daily_amount
from tbWorkingDays wd cross apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from tblBudget b 
      where wd.date >= b.date
      order by b.date desc
     ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sum as an analytical function to get the number of workingdays pr month, then divide out

Here is a functioning solution

```
with tally as
(
SELECT
row_number() over (order by (select null))-1 n
from (values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)) a(a)
cross join (values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)) b(b)
cross join (values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)) c(c)
)
, tbWorkingDays as
(
select
cast(dateadd(day,n,'2020-01-01') as date) [Date],
iif(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,cast(dateadd(day,n,'2020-01-01') as date)) in (1,7),0,1) WorkingDay 
from tally
where n<365
)
, tbBudget AS
(
select * from
(values 
(cast('2020-08-01' as date), cast(1000 as decimal(19,2)))
,(cast('2020-09-01' as date), cast(2000as decimal(19,2)))
,(cast('2020-10-01' as date), cast(3000as decimal(19,2)))
) a([Date],[Amount])
)
select 
    a.[Date]
    ,a.WorkingDay*
    (b.Amount/
    sum(a.WorkingDay) over (partition by year(a.Date)*100+month(a.Date)))
from tbWorkingDays a
inner join tbBudget b
on a.Date between b.Date and dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,b.date))
```

The work is done here:

```
select 
    a.[Date]
    ,a.WorkingDay*
    (b.Amount/
    sum(a.WorkingDay) over (partition by year(a.Date)*100+month(a.Date)))
from tbWorkingDays a
inner join tbBudget b
on a.Date between b.Date and dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,b.date))
```

The expression

```
sum(a.WorkingDay) over (partition by year(a.Date)*100+month(a.Date))
```

Sums the number of workingdays for the current month. I then join against the budget and take the sum for the month and divide by the expression above.

To make sure there only is budget on workingdays, I simply multiply by "workingday", since 0 is a non workingday, the sum will be 0 for all non workingdays.